# How to create new user with custom home directory in rpm

Tags: rpm

I'm attempting to create an RPM that needs to add a user with a custom home directory. In the preinstall script, it attempts to execute this command (yes, myapp already exists):

```
useradd -c "My Application's User" -d /usr/myapp -f 0 -s /bin/bash -g myapp myapp
```

If I execute this command as root, it works fine. If I execute this command via RPM when running as root, I get the following error:

```
useradd: cannot create directory /usr/myapp
```

Does RPM run as a different user when installing/running install scripts? Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish?

Thanks!

Comment: rpm scriptlets run as whatever user is installing the rpm I believe (almost always root in practice). What do you get if you add `ls -l /usr` right before that useradd call? Can you manually `mkdir /usr/myapp` at that point in your `%pre` script?

Comment: If I do a `ls -l /usr` I get a listing of the /usr directory. Nothing out of the ordinary.

As for the mkdir command, I'm unsure that would get me anywhere because the directory would be owned by root, right?

Comment: So ls doesn't list `/usr/myapp` as anything then? Ok. The point of the mkdir is to test whether that fails also (and to see what error it fails with). `mkdir /usr/myapp; echo mkdir returned $?`. (And you can always `chown myapp:myapp /usr/myapp` to fix the ownership but that's not the point.)

Comment: I added the mkdir command and oddly everything "worked" other than needing to adjust the permission values. It even assigned the dir to the "myapp" user. I was curious, so I added `whoami` to the script and it confirmed it was root. I have a sufficient workaround now, but I'm still very curious why it doesn't work within the preinstall script even though the user is root.

Comment: What version of CentOS/RH/etc. is this? And a `mkdir` at the same place in the `%pre` as the `useradd` (directly before it presumably) worked just fine? I'm assuming if you pull that back out it starts to fail again? Is this during system installation (kickstart) or on a running system?

Comment: RHEL 7. Running system. And your assumptions are correct.

Comment: That error means that `mkdir(2)` failed. Unfortunately, `useradd` doesn't do anything with `errno` so we can't tell why. If you create the directory with `mkdir` then remove it with `rmdir` and then run that `useradd` does it still fail? Do you have `strace` on your system? Could you run that `useradd` in `%pre` via `strace` (with `-o` to send the output to a file) and see what it says is happening?

Answer (score 2):

It might be connected to SELinux. Try to run `setenforce 0` before the useradd, or disable SELinux in /etc/selinux/config, BUT I must warn you: this is not a good practice. Creating user not under /home/ will cause to troubles if you want to use SELinux (and you probably want). I think you better reconsider this. What is the reason for setting home directory under /usr ?

Comment: The user isn't a normal user, but the user of the application. Running an application as root doesn't feel like a good idea when the application doesn't need root access. Other examples of this that I've seen is apache running as an httpd user or Oracle running as an oracle user.

Comment: Still, try to separate the user home dir and the application binaries / data. Is any of the above helped?

Answer (score 0):

This usually happen when you do:

```
useradd -d /usr/something/myapp
```

and /usr/something does not exist. /usr/something have to exist. You can call do

```
   mkdir -p /usr/something
```

at the top of %pre